# Return MYSQLi Prepared Statement Query and Bind Results an an Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I want to put the result of a mysqli prepared statement into an array and return the array for use in another page.

The code is presented below.

```
function getPermission($mysqli , $email) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT m.email , g.permission 
                                  FROM members m  
                                  INNER JOIN members_groups q ON m.member_id = q.member_id  
                                  INNER JOIN groups g on q.group_id = g.group_id                                                    
                                  WHERE email = ?")) 
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_email, $user_perms);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '  ID: '.$user_email; //prints the results.
        }

    }

}
```

I want to place the query results into an array and return the array.

Note: Am using a wamp server with php and mysql in windows 7. I tried to use the `$stmt->getresults` method, but it returns nothing.

Comment: You aren't storing anything to an array here. If it is going to be used on another page you are going to need to store it somewhere; maybe SESSION..

Comment: Yes, I want a way to create the array and store the results in the array as the while loop iterates to fetch the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to store it in an array, one by one, in your loop:

```
    $results = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $results[] = array(
            "email" => $user_email,
            "perms" => $user_perms
        );
    }
    return $results;
```

If you need this array in another file, where you include this function, this will work, but if you need it in another request, PHP will have to run this code again to have the array filled.

If you need this array during the session, then consider putting the result in a session variable:

```
 $_SESSION['myarray'] = $results;
```

Then in the function, first check if the above session variable is set, and if so, immediately return that value. Only when it is not yet set, you perform the rest of the function.